# Trying to compare two integers. It is giving me an int error in one of my functions

Tags: python-3.x, casting

When I try to compare two integers I am getting an int error.  Saying that it can't compare an int and a string but I am casting the input(string) to an int.  Can someone explain why this happened?

I tried to int cast userInput = int(input(PROMPT) then I returned userInput.  Then I try to compare my computerChoice to userInput and am getting an error.

```
def userInput():
    userInput = int(input(PROMPT))
    return userInput
```

Here is entire code:
Python3 btw:

```
PROMPT = "Please enter an integer: "


WELCOME = "THE GUESSING GAME"


#get input
def userInput():
    userInput = int(input(PROMPT))
    return userInput

#get computer guess
def computerGuess():
    import random
    computerGuess = (int)(random.random()*6)
    return computerGuess

def game(userInput, computerInput):
    while userInput != computerInput:
        print("Try again")
        userInput()
        if userInput == computerInput:
            print("You win!!")      
def main():
    
    #get user Input in main
    theInput = userInput()

    #computer input 
    computer = computerGuess()

    #launch game 
    game(theInput, computer)
    



main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you choose for the argument representing the user's input (`userInput`) in your `game` function is the same name as the function to capture user's input. So, in the scope of the `game` function, `userInput` is integer, but the you try to use it as a function (and `int` type is not callable).

Moreover, the return value of the `userInput()` function is not used to update the value of the variable `userInput`, so if the first value provided by the user is different from `computerInput`, the loop will continue forever.

If you change the name of the argument in the `game` function and update the value provided by the user, the program works as expected:

```py
def game(user_input, computer_input):
    while user_input != computer_input:
        print("Try again")
        user_input = userInput()
        if user_input == computer_input:
            print("You win!!")
```

Otherwise, you can change a little bit your code, removing the user input from the arguments of the game function:

```py
def game(computer_input):
    while userInput() != computer_input:
        print("Try again")
    print("You win!!")
```

Obviously, you must remove also `theInput = userInput()` from the `main` function. Actually, you can get rid of your main function, using directly the `game` function instead:

```py
game(computerGuess())
```

However, also the choice of the names of the variables in the `userInput` and `computerGuess` functions is not wise: you should avoid naming variables inside a function with the same name of the function because it is confusing and makes your code more prone to errors.

Another suggestion: you can easily improve your program by limiting the range of the values: for instance, generate a random integer between 1 and 10 and ask the user to guess it. You can modify the `computerGuess` using [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) instead of `random.random` and adding a check that does not allow to the user to input values outside the range [1; 10].